# Retrieving updated value via @ManagedProperty / notifying other beans of updated value of a property

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have a `SessionScoped` bean say `UserSession` which holds a String property `token` which acts as a authenticated token for the logged in user. This token is injected into other `SessionScoped` and `ViewScoped` beans so that they can consume this token and perform stuff. I have no problems injecting the property.

However, there's a use case wherein the `token` in the `UserSession` itself is replaced by a different String. And once I do this, the other beans still refer to the old value of the `token` which results in invalid access.

How can I notify the other beans of this value change? or do I retrieve bean instance through

`FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                Application app = context.getApplication();

                UserSession session = (UserSession) app.evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{userSession}", UserSession.class);`

And then retrieve `token` as `session.getToken()`?
I'm using Mojarra 2.0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why that is a problem. This more sounds like as if you're copying the property like as:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
private OtherBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userSession}")
    private UserSession userSession;

    private String token;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { 
        this.token = userSession.getToken();
    }

    public void someAction() {
        doSomethingWith(token);
    }

    public void otherAction() {
        doSomethingElseWith(token);
    }

    // ...
}
```

while you should rather be accessing it directly:

```
    // ...

    public void someAction() {
        doSomethingWith(userSession.getToken());
    }

    public void otherAction() {
        doSomethingElseWith(userSession.getToken());
    }

    // ...
```

Fix your beans accordingly to get rid of the private token property which contains the copy and just let all methods get it from the injected bean directly.

Comment: Sorry I was a little unclear there. I am actually referring to the token property only. Like  @ManagedProperty(value="#{userSession.token}")
private String token; as I didn't need the whole UserSession object!

Comment: Then change it accordingly so that you only have a `#{userSession}` managed property and use `userSession.getToken()` instead of `token` :) Strings are immutable so you're basically copying the token instead of referencing it. Better is to inject the whole bean. Basically just the reference will be copied (which is cheaper!) and all changes will just be reflected back.

Comment: OMG! I had completely ignored the immutability part! Thanks @BalusC :)